# Order ArrayList with Int and String in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sorting, arraylist, jvm-arguments

I have the given array

```
val things = arrayOf<Any>("Jack", 8, 2, 6, "King", 5, 3, "Queen", "Jack");
```

Below is the code I have used

```
 things.set(things.indexOf("Jack"), 11);
  things.set(things.indexOf("Queen"), 12);
  things.set(things.indexOf("King"), 13);
  things.sort();
    
    things.set(things.indexOf(11), "Jack"));
    things.set(things.indexOf(12), "Queen");
    things.set(things.indexOf(13), "King");
    things.joinToString(":");
    things.forEach { System.out.print(it) }
```

Here is the error I keep getting

```
Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
Expecting an element
```

After removing the trailing bracket, I now get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
 at java.lang.String.compareTo (:-1) 
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort (:-1) 
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort (:-1)
```

Comment: why does this have an extra bracket at the end ?  `things.set(things.indexOf(11), "Jack"));`

Comment: oh, that is a mistake, please, check the update to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've 2 `Jack` in your list, so when you use `indexOf()`, it returns the index of the first occurrence of that item.

```
things.set(things.indexOf("Jack"), 11);
things.set(things.indexOf("Queen"), 12);
things.set(things.indexOf("King"), 13);
```

This changes your list to

`[11, 8, 2, 6, 13, 5, 3, 12, Jack]`

Now, when you apply the `sort()` operation on `things`. It throws `ClassCastException` on `Jack` as it's a `string`, not an `int`.

---

To find all the `indexes` of a value, so you can replace them, you can create an `extension` function that returns a list of all the indices for a value.

```
fun <T> Array<T>.indexesOfAll(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<Int> {
    return mapIndexedNotNull { index, any ->
        index.takeIf {
            predicate(any)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can use this `indexesOfAll` function to get the `indexes` of all the items for a particular condition.

```
things.indexesOfAll { it == "Jack" }.forEach {
    things.set(it, 11)
}
```

You can do the same for all other values too.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you have "Jack" two times in it. `things.set(things.indexOf("Jack"), 11);` only changes the first one to 11, not the second one.

```
val things = arrayOf<Any>("Jack", 8, 2, 6, "King", 5, 3, "Queen", "Jack");
things.set(things.indexOf("Jack"), 11);
things.set(things.indexOf("Queen"), 12);
things.set(things.indexOf("King"), 13);
println(things.contentToString()) //prints [11, 8, 2, 6, 13, 5, 3, 12, Jack]
```

---

Now, how I maybe would do it, is like this:

```
fun main() {
    val things = arrayOf("Jack", 8, 2, 6, "King", 5, 3, "Queen", "Jack")
    things.sortWith(compareBy { it.toInt() })
    println(things.contentToString()) //prints [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, Jack, Jack, Queen, King]
}

val mapping = mapOf("Jack" to 11, "Queen" to 12, "King" to 13)

fun Any.toInt() : Int {
    if (this is Int) return this
    return mapping[this] ?: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the other answers solve the problem at hand, there is a base issue at play. Normally you would want to avoid having multi-typed arrays (or any type of collection).
A better solution would be to introduce and abstraction to represent both types of data as the same class and make that class implement the `Comparable` interface.

An implementation example of this:

```
sealed class Card(val name: String) : Comparable<Card> {
  abstract val order: Int
  override fun compareTo(other: Card): Int =
    order - other.order

  override fun toString(): String = name

  class Number(value: Int) : Card(value.toString()) {
    override val order: Int = value
  }

  object Ace : Card("Ace") {
    override val order: Int = 1
  }

  object Jack : Card("Jack") {
    override val order: Int = 11
  }

  object Queen : Card("Queen") {
    override val order: Int = 12
  }

  object King : Card("King") {
    override val order: Int = 13
  }
}
```

then you could use it like this:

```
println(listOf(Card.Number(2), Card.Ace, Card.Queen, Card.Number(3)).sorted())
```